# Maven JarJar Plugin: Exclude 'provided' scope?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, jarjar

Is there a way to have the Maven JarJar plugin exclude items in the 'provided' scope? This seems pretty straightforward... if something is provided, why would I want to include it in my megajar?

Comment: Can you please post your configuration? I'm trying to do something similar. 10x ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a "zap" rule might help. Example [here](http://code.google.com/p/jarjar/wiki/CommandLineDocs)

Comment: I'm already manually excluding things via the exclude tag in Maven. I'd just like to know if there was a way to filter out dependencies in specific scopes.